# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Player?'

Tags: swift, xcode

I have little problem with my code. When I call on the Player class to my array in my `"TeamNamesViewController"` I get the error message

> "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type
>   'Player?'"

The error appears on this row

```
NewPLayer.append(InputNameTextField.text!)
```

Under my func `InsertNewName()`

But if I only makes a String array like  `var NewPLayer: [String?] = []` in my TeamNamesViewController it works fine!

What should I do?

```
___

    import Foundation

    class Player {
        var name : String?
         var score : Int

        init(name: String?, score: Int) {
            self.name=name
            self.score=score
        }
    }

    import UIKit

    class TeamNamesViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate {
        var NumberOfTeams = 0
        let NewTeamCell =  "NewTeamCell"

        @IBOutlet weak var InputNameTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var TableViewTeams: UITableView!
        var person = Player(name: nil, score: 0)
        var NewPLayer: [Player?] = []

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            InputNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return NewPLayer.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NewTeamCell, for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = NewPLayer[indexPath.row]?.name
            return cell
        }

        @IBAction func AddTeamButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

            InsertNewName()
            if NumberOfTeams + 1 < NewPLayer.count {
                NumberOfTeams += 1
                InputNameTextField?.text = NewPLayer[NumberOfTeams]?.name
            } else {
                NumberOfTeams = 0
            }
        }

        func InsertNewName(){
            NewPLayer.append(InputNameTextField.text!) //The error appears here


            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: NewPLayer.count - 1, section: 0)

            TableViewTeams.beginUpdates()
            TableViewTeams.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            TableViewTeams.endUpdates()

            InputNameTextField.text = ""
            view.endEditing(true)

            print(NewPLayer)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                NewPLayer.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                TableViewTeams.beginUpdates()
                TableViewTeams.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                TableViewTeams.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't name your variables and constants with a capitalized first letter (e.g: `InputNameTextField`, `NewPlayer` or `NewTeamCell`). Swift users will expect names begining with a capital letter to be types (struct, class, protocol, enum), not variables. This make your code unclear and hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NewPlayer` is of type `[Player]` which means it will take an object of type `Player`.

```
NewPLayer.append(Player(name:InputNameTextField.text! , score : 0 ) )
```

Also, don't declare variables in uppercase. Follow this [RayWendelich's guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#naming) to understand better.

Answer (score 2):

First of all please conform to the naming convention to name variables and functions with starting lowercase letter and create the array with non-optional items

```
var newPLayer : [Player] = []
```

---

The error is pretty clear. You are going to append a `String` to a `Player` array which is not possible.

You have to create a `Player` instance from the string

```
newPLayer.append( Player(name: InputNameTextField.text, score: 0))
```

Side note:

Delete the `begin-/endUpdates()` lines. They have no effect.